# bumblebee don't publish image --> fuerte

Tags: ros, camera1394, ros-fuerte, stereo, bumblebee2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.04
ROS: Fuerte
Camera: Bumblebee2 -> svn co `cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bumblebee2`
Other Software include: Bumblebee2 ROS package, libdc1394-22, Coriander programme.
Other links cheked:
```

> http://answers.ros.org/question/11492/bumblebee2-or-bumblebee1394-this-is-the-question
>
> http://answers.ros.org/questions/37289/revisions/
>
> http://answers.ros.org/question/33666/error-with-rosmake-bumblebee2-fuerte
>
> http://answers.ros.org/question/10152/bumblebee2-640x480-under-diamondback/?answer=14894#post-id-14894
>
> http://ninghang.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/running-bumblebee2-on-ros-tutorial.html

And I can't run bumblebee2 in fuerte. I follow 2 lines: one with the updated package camera1394 like this:

```
<launch>
  <!-- name node (and topic) after parameter file -->
  <node pkg="camera1394" type="camera1394_node"
        name="bumblebee2" output="screen">
    <rosparam
       file="$(find DemoROS)/launch/bumblebee2.yaml" /> 
  </node>
</launch>
```

and the yaml

```
# Sample camera parameters for the Bumblebee2
#guid: 08144361026320a0 (defaults to first camera found)
#video_mode: 1024x768_mono #for a single grayscale frame
video_mode: 1024x768_mono16 #for bumblebee2
fps: 15
bayer_pattern: GRBG
bayer_method: Nearest
settings_url: file:///opt/ros/camera_settings/bumblebee_right.yaml
settings_url2: file:///opt/ros/camera_settings/bumblebee_left.yaml
# these all default to automatic settings:
#brightness: 511
#exposure: 256
#gain: 150
shutter: -1
#whitebalance: "2000 2000"
```

$ roslaunch DemoROS bumblebee2_lsi.launch

```
[ INFO] [1360084095.413930703]: Found camera with GUID b09d010090cf10
[ INFO] [1360084095.414026074]: No guid specified, using first camera found, GUID: b09d010090cf10
[ INFO] [1360084095.414056375]: camera model: Point Grey Research Bumblebee2 BB2-08S2C
[ WARN] [1360084095.414878719]: [Nearest] Bayer decoding in the driver is DEPRECATED; image_proc decoding preferred.
[ERROR] [1360084095.414906986]: Unknown Bayer method [Nearest]. Using ROS image_proc instead.
[ERROR] [1360084095.415115555]: unknown bayer pattern [GRBG]
[ INFO] [1360084095.418217826]: [00b09d010090cf10] opened: 1024x768_mono16, 15 fps, 400 Mb/s
```

This way publish one
[image http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/4431/1024x768mono16.jpg](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/4431/1024x768mono16.jpg)
with both camera data mixed. I try de-interlaced it but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I try with other formats like Format7_mode3 with dynamic_reconfigure pkg and this is the result:
[image http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/4717/format7mode3.jpg](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/4717/format7mode3.jpg)

My bumblebee2_lsi program is this:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/console.h>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
//#include <camera_info_manager/camera_info.h>
#include <camera_info_manager/camera_info_manager.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/SensorLevels.h>
//#include "bumblebee2.h"
//#include "bumblebee2/Bumblebee2Config.h"

namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;


/** @file

@brief camera1394 is a ROS driver for 1394 Firewire digital cameras.

This is a ROS port of the Player driver for 1394 cameras, using
libdc1394.  It provides a reliable driver with minimal dependencies,
intended to fill a role in the ROS image pipeline similar to the other
ROS camera drivers.

The ROS image pipeline provides Bayer filtering at a higher level (in
image_proc).  In some cases it is useful to run the driver without the
entire image pipeline, so libdc1394 Bayer decoding is also provided.

@par Advertises

 - \b camera/image_raw topic (sensor_msgs/Image) raw 2D camera images
   (only raw if \b bayer_method is \b NONE).

 - \b camera/camera_info topic (sensor_msgs/CameraInfo) Calibration
   information for each image.


@par Subscribes

 - None


@par Parameters

- \b frame_id : @b [string] camera frame of reference
     (Default: device node name)
- \b guid : @b [string] The guid of the camera (Default: "NONE")
- \b fps : @b [real] Frames per second (Default: 15.0)
- \b iso_speed : @b [int] ISO transfer speed (Default: 400)
- \b video_mode : @b [string] Desired image resolution and type (Default "800x600_mono").  The driver supports the following values:
                "320x240_yuv422"
        "640x480_mono"
        "640x480_yuv422"
        "640x480_rgb"
        "800x600_mono"
        "800x600_yuv422"
        "1024x768_mono"
        "1024x768_yuv422"
        "1280x960_mono"
        "1280x960_yuv422"
- \b bayer_pattern : @b [string] The pattern of the Bayer filter to use (Default: "NONE").  The driver supports the following values:
                "BGGR"
        "GRBG"
        "RGGB"
        "GBRG"
        "NONE"
- \b bayer_method : @b [string] The type of Bayer processing to perform (Default: "NONE").  The driver supports the following values:
                "NONE"
        "DownSample" (1/2 size image)
        "Nearest"
        "Bilinear"
        "HQ"
        "VNG"
        "AHD"
- \b exposure : @b [int] Sets the camera exposure feature to value.
- \b shutter : @b [int] Sets the camera shutter feature to value.  -1 turns on auto shutter.
- \b whitebalance : @b [string] (e.g. "2000 2000") Sets the Blue/U and Red/V components of white balance.  "auto" turns on auto white balance.
- \b gain : @b [int] Sets the camera gain feature to value.  -1 turns on auto gain.
- \b brightness : @b [int] Sets the camera brightness feature to value.


@todo Make array of supported image encoding values, check parameter
settings against that. Make enum type for dynamic reconfiguration.

*/
class Bumblebee2lsi
{
private:
  ros::NodeHandle privNH_;              // private node handle
  image_transport::ImageTransport *it_;
  std::string camera_name_;
  std::string frame_id_;
  sensor_msgs::Image image_;
  sensor_msgs::Image left_image_;
  sensor_msgs::Image right_image_;
  sensor_msgs::CameraInfo left_cam_info_;
  sensor_msgs::CameraInfo right_cam_info_;

  sensor_msgs::CameraInfo cinfo_;

  /** image transport publish interface */
  image_transport::CameraPublisher left_image_pub_;
  image_transport::CameraPublisher right_image_pub_;

  bool start_;

public:

  Bumblebee2lsi() {
    privNH_ = ros::NodeHandle("~");

    it_ = new image_transport::ImageTransport(privNH_);

    left_image_pub_ = it_->advertiseCamera("left/image_raw", 1);
    right_image_pub_ = it_->advertiseCamera("right/image_raw", 2);

    start_ = false;

  }

  ~Bumblebee2lsi()
  {
    delete it_;
  }


  /** Update the bumblebee2 calibration data */
  /** Author : Soonhac Hong (sh2723@columbia.edu) */
  /** Date : 5/24/2010 */
  /** Note : Calibration data is needed to show disparity image using image_view with stereo_view.*/
  void updateBumblebee2CalibrationData()
  {
      double left_D_data[] = {-0.29496962080028677, 0.12120859315219049, -0.0019941265153862824, 0.0012058185627261283, 0.0};
      double left_K_data[] = {543.60636929659358, 0.0, 321.7411723319629, 0.0, 543.25622524820562, 268.04452669345528, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
      double left_R_data[] = {0.99980275533925467, -0.018533834763323875, -0.0071377436911170388, 0.018542709766871161, 0.99982737377597841, 0.0011792212393866724, 0.0071146560377753926, -0.0013113417539480422, 0.9999738306837177};
      double left_P_data[] = {514.20203529502226, 0.0, 334.37528610229492, 0.0, 0.0, 514.20203529502226, 268.46113204956055, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0};
      double right_D_data[] =  {-0.2893208200535437, 0.11215776927066376, -0.0003854904042866552, 0.00081197271575971614, 0.0};
      double right_K_data[] =  {541.66040340873735, 0.0, 331.73470962829737, 0.0, 541.60313005445187, 265.72960150703699, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
      double right_R_data[] =  {0.99986888001551244, -0.012830354497672055, -0.0098795131453283894, 0.012818040762902759, 0.99991698911455085, -0.001308705884349387, 0.0098954841986237611, 0.001181898284639702, 0.99995034002140304};
      double right_P_data[] =  {514.20203529502226, 0.0, 334.37528610229492, -232.44101555000066, 0.0, 514.20203529502226, 268.46113204956055, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0};

      left_cam_info_.D.resize(5);
      right_cam_info_.D.resize(5);
      memcpy(&left_cam_info_.D[0], &left_D_data[0], sizeof(left_D_data));
      memcpy(&left_cam_info_.K[0], &left_K_data[0], sizeof(left_K_data));
      memcpy(&left_cam_info_.R[0], &left_R_data[0], sizeof(left_R_data));
      memcpy(&left_cam_info_.P[0], &left_P_data[0], sizeof(left_P_data));
      memcpy(&right_cam_info_.D[0], &right_D_data[0], sizeof(right_D_data));
      memcpy(&right_cam_info_.K[0], &right_K_data[0], sizeof(right_K_data));
      memcpy(&right_cam_info_.R[0], &right_R_data[0], sizeof(right_R_data));
      memcpy(&right_cam_info_.P[0], &right_P_data[0], sizeof(right_P_data));
  }


  void updateDataCallbackImage(const sensor_msgs::Image msg)
  {
      image_ = msg;
      // get current CameraInfo data from topic /camera/image_info
      left_cam_info_ = right_cam_info_= cinfo_;

      left_image_.header.frame_id = right_image_.header.frame_id = image_.header.frame_id = left_cam_info_.header.frame_id = right_cam_info_.header.frame_id = image_.header.frame_id;

      //update bumblebee2 calibration data
      updateBumblebee2CalibrationData();

        // Read data from the image_ via topic
      if(start_){


        left_cam_info_.header.stamp = right_cam_info_.header.stamp = left_image_.header.stamp = right_image_.header.stamp=image_.header.stamp;
        left_cam_info_.height = right_cam_info_.height = left_image_.height = right_image_.height=image_.height;
        left_cam_info_.width = right_cam_info_.width = left_image_.width = right_image_.width=image_.width;

        left_image_.encoding = right_image_.encoding = image_.encoding;


        //Split image into left image and right image
        left_image_.step = right_image_.step = image_.step;
        int image_size = image_.height*image_.step;
        left_image_.data.resize(image_size);
        right_image_.data.resize(image_size);


        memcpy(&right_image_.data[0], &image_.data[0], image_size);     // the image of right camera is the first half of the deinterlaced image.
        memcpy(&left_image_.data[0], &image_.data[image_size], image_size);     // the image of left camera is the second half of the deinterlaced image.

        // Publish it via image_transport
        left_image_pub_.publish(left_image_, left_cam_info_);
        right_image_pub_.publish(right_image_, right_cam_info_);
      }
  }

  void updateDataCallbackInfo(const sensor_msgs::CameraInfo info)
  {
      cinfo_ = info;
      start_ = true;
  }


}; // end Bumblebee2lsi class definition



/** Main entry point */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "bumblebee2_lsi");
  ros::NodeHandle node;

  Bumblebee2lsi bumblebee2;

  ros::Subscriber sub_image = node.subscribe("camera/image_raw", 1000, &Bumblebee2lsi::updateDataCallbackImage, &bumblebee2);
  ros::Subscriber sub_info = node.subscribe("camera/camera_info", 1000, &Bumblebee2lsi::updateDataCallbackInfo, &bumblebee2);


  while (node.ok())
  {
      ros::spinOnce();
  }


  return 0;
}
```

It is a copy paste from `http://cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bumblebee2/` and modify a little.

the results are the same image in both topics (right and left). I don't know why.

The other line to follow is using the code from `http://cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bumblebee2` and try to compile. I follow that `http://answers.ros.org/question/33666/error-with-rosmake-bumblebee2-fuerte` and I can compile all package and solve the segmentation fault but no images is published (the topics don't start to publish nothing).

What I am doing wrong? I hope somebody can help me. Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54375/bumblebee-don%27t-publish-image---%3E-fuerte/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-05**:
These questions come up often enough that I wish we could support an "official" ROS bumblebee driver. It's not all that different from the basic camera1394 driver, which I do support. Unfortunately, I have no bumblebee hardware for testing, so I cannot do that myself.

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2013-02-06**:
Thanks for the comment ;) Maybe this code help a little to understand the problem: `http://cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bumblebee2/src/dev_camera1394.cpp` (line 725) and the use of this code here : `http://cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bumblebee2/src/bumblebee2.cpp` (line 382)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pease check our firewire stereo driver http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394stereo, which we are using for bumblebee2 cameras with Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1